# (Unix) piping tail -f to festival

Tags: unix, sed, grep, piping, festival

I'm trying to send a stream of the end of a file (via tail -f) to festival, which is a text to speech program. **tail -f ./filename | festival --tts** works fine for this.

Here's my problem:
I'd like change the stream coming out of tail -f so that festival can better synthesize it, and to avoid it speaking entire timestamps. I know that programs like sed and grep can do this. unfortunately **tail -f ./filename | sed 's/:/ says/' | festival --tts** does not output any sound.

yes, I have check to see if **tail -f ./filename | sed 's/:/ says/'** outputs anything, and it does that just fine.

I've also tried this with grep and I can not get **festival --tts** to say anything after I've edited my stream.

Anything that allows my stream to be edited, then spoken would be welcomed, I'm not tied down to sed and grep.

Comment: The problem is likely buffering of I/O by sed such that it doesn't write anything for periods of time.  You can test this by replacing tail -f with just a tail command.  There are usually ways to change buffering, but often it's command-specific.  Try `sed --help` or `sed -?` to see if any options mention unbuffered output or the like.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f` by itself won't work because festival is waiting for the input stream to close before it outputs audio.  With `tail -f` as input, the input stream will never close.

However, you can use the bash `read` command to break the tail output up, run it through grep,  and pass it to festival in a separate process with a script like this:

```
tail -f ./filename | grep something |  while read line; do 
  echo "$line" | festival --tts
done
```

If your grep filter isn't returning much data, it will take some time before the grep buffer fills and flushes.  To reduce the size of the grep buffer, use `grep --line-buffered something`.  sed has similar buffering capabilities, and you can use the `-u` (unbuffered) option in sed to disable them.

Comment: you might also try moving `festival` to end of the loop, i.e. `... done | festival --tts` to avoid repeated process creation for `festival`, but maybe the buffering problem will happen here too. Good luck to all.